# Como importar uma variável dentro de uma função de uma classe?

Tags: php, classes, funções

Gostaria de pegar a `$valortotal` e levá-la pra dentro de uma função de uma classe como pode ser visto no exemplo abaixo. Obrigado.

```
$valortotal = 15.00;

class CreatePaymentRequestLightbox
{
    public static function main()
    {
        $pedido_total = $valortotal;
    ....
.....
```

Comment: Acho que deve ser possível passá-la como argumento para a função `main`.

Comment: Pode demonstrar como eu faria isso @qmechanik .... Obrigado.

Comment: ou ela pode ser uma variável global, mas acho muito melhor passar como parâmetro da `main()` também

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Uma possibilidade seria passar a variável como argumento para a função `main`.

```php
class CreatePaymentRequestLightbox{
    public function main($valortotal){
        $pedido_total = $valortotal;
        echo $pedido_total;
    }
}

$valortotal = 15.00;
$paymentRequest = new CreatePaymentRequestLightbox();
$paymentRequest->main($valortotal);
```

[Ver `demonstração`](http://ideone.com/AZ6C4r)

Ou usar uma variável publica da classe:

```php
class CreatePaymentRequestLightbox{
    public $pedido_total = 0;

    public function main(){
        echo $this->pedido_total;
    }
}

$valortotal = 15.00;
$paymentRequest = new CreatePaymentRequestLightbox();
$paymentRequest->pedido_total = $valortotal;
$paymentRequest->main();
```

[Ver `demonstração`](http://ideone.com/3fqR6j)

Ou usar uma variável privada e mudar o valor com uma função pública:

```php
class CreatePaymentRequestLightbox{
    private $pedido_total = 0;

    public function editarPedidoTotal($pedido_total){
        $this->pedido_total = $pedido_total;
    }
    public function main(){
        echo $this->pedido_total;
    }
}

$valortotal = 15.00;
$paymentRequest = new CreatePaymentRequestLightbox();
$paymentRequest->editarPedidoTotal($valortotal);
$paymentRequest->main();
```

[Ver `demonstração`](http://ideone.com/zbzIcq)

Answer (score 4):

Faça `main()` aceitar um parâmetro.

```
$valortotal = 15.00;

class CreatePaymentRequestLightbox
    {

        public static function main($valortotal)
             {

                  $pedido_total = $valortotal;
```

Dessa forma você passa o valor direto ou a variável quando for chamar a função

```
$valortotal = 15.00;
$paymentRequest = new CreatePaymentRequestLightbox()->main($valortotal);
```

Answer (score 4):

Caso o valor já esteja dentro da classe

```
class CreatePaymentRequestLightbox
    {

private $valorTotal = '150.00';

        public static function main()
             {

                  $pedido_total = $this->valorTotal;
```

Caso você vá pegar fora da classe para jogar dentro

```
class CreatePaymentRequestLightbox
    {

public $valorTotal;

        public static function main()
             {

                  $pedido_total = $this->valorTotal;
}
}

$classe = new CreatePaymentRequestLightbox;
$classe->valorTotal = '150.00';
```

Answer (score 1):

Só complementando as demais respostas e também exemplificando o [comentário do @ErlonCharles](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/64774/como-importar-uma-vari%c3%a1vel-dentro-de-uma-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-uma-classe#comment132614_64774), o que não é o recomendado para todos os casos (como já citado) e quase sempre a melhor opção é passar o valor por parâmetro.

Porém em alguns casos, como objeto de conexão, o melhor seja usar uma variável global:

```
$connection = new PDO();

class AlgumaClasse
{
    public static function main($valortotal)
    {
        global $connection;
        $connection->query("INSERT INTO valores (valor) VALUES ({$valortotal})");
    }
}

AlgumaClasse::main(15.00);
```

Comment: Variável global é uma boa ideia !!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Não é recomendado, mas vc poderia usar assim também:

```
$valortotal = 15.00;

class CreatePaymentRequestLightbox
{
    public static function main()
    {
        global $valortotal;
        $pedido_total = $valortotal;
    ...
...
```